# Solve $x(x-1)y''+6x^2y'+3y=0$ using Frobenius's Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $x(x-1)y''+6x^2y'+3y=0$ using Frobenius's Method

[image]

I can't solve this ODE. How can I get first two term? and indicial equation is also very confusing. I can solve two term recurrence relation by Frobenius Method, but it's too hard to solve three term recurrence relation.

P.S Recurrence relation that I write above is correct. And Sorry for my bad English

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).